# Сборка .NET Core приложения завершается с ошибкой на linux, когда зависимая библиотека имеет несколько TargetFrameworks

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-cli

Есть веб-приложение `WebApp.csproj` .Net Core 3.1, которое использует библиотеку классов `Lib.csproj`, рассчитанную на несколько фреймворков: `netstandard 2.0` и `net45`.

Т.е имется примерно следующая структура проектов:

**Lib.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45;</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  //...

</Project>
```

**WebApp.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  //...

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="Lib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

При попытке билда этого веб-приложения на Linux-машине появляется ошибка:

> ##[error]...../dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5):
> Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5
> were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
> (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your
> application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

Т.е. dotnet-cli, как я понял, пытается сбилдать библиотеку `Lib.csproj` в том числе и для TargetFramework = `net45`, хотя ему нужен только `net standard 2.0`. До того, как я добавил для проекта `Lib.csproj` `TargetFramework net45` проект успешно билдался на Linux.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Можно, конечно, каждый проект собирать по отдельности, но это плохой вариант.

Comment: Почему не собирать только `WebApp.csproj`?

Comment: [Это](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/18/conditional-targetframeworks-for-multitargeted-net-sdk-projects-on-crossplatform-builds) видели?

Comment: Если у вас в библиотеке нет кода под директивами 4.5 - оставьте только netstandard2.0

Comment: @Vasek нет, не видел. Пробовать уже не стану, нашел другое решение. Чуть позже опубликую

Comment: @PashaPash к сожалению, есть. И этот код нужен, поскольку эта библиотека потом импортится как nuget-пакет в другой .net framework 4.5 - проект, относящийся к другому солюшену